# Pandas Replacing Current Value with Previous Value if NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
     name     age
0    bob      10
1    sal      5
2    NaN      22
```

Row 2 in the Name column is null, so I want to replace the `NaN` value with the previous value, in this case Sal, so my result would look like this:

```
     name     age
0    bob      10
1    sal      5
2    sal      22
```

Here is what I'm currently playing with:

```
for index,row in dataframe.head().iterrows():
     if open_first_page.isnull(open_first_page["name"]):
          print("hi")
```

I can't get the isnull function to even work though. Any suggestions? Once I get that recognized, I'll see if I can grab the previous value somehow.

Side Note: What I'm doing might seem odd, but I'm doing some ETL via Python, so it works with what I am doing.

Comment: Use `df.Name = df.Name.ffill()`

Comment: So change `if open_first_page.isnull(open_first_page["name"]):` to `if pd.isnan(row["name"]):`

Comment: I'm good now, thank you!